# Unable to use debugging in SASM

Tags: assembly, gcc, gdb, nasm, sasm

Im learning NASM and trying to debug this code:

```
; jump.asm
extern printf
section .data
    number1 dq 42
    number2 dq 41
    fmt1 db "NUMBER1 >= NUMBER2",10,0
    fmt2 db "NUMBER1 < NUMBER2",10,0
section .bss
section .text
    global main
main:
    mov rbp,rsp
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    mov rax, [number1]
    mov rbx, [number2]
    cmp rax,rbx
    jge greater
    mov rdi,fmt2
    mov rax,0
    call printf
    jmp exit
greater:
    mov rdi,fmt1
    mov rax,0
    call printf
exit:
    mov rsp,rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

It builds ok, and executes as expected. But wherever I put breakpoint and try to use Debug option - debugging not performing, build log:

```
Build log:
[01:29:05] Build started...
[01:29:05] Built successfully.
[01:29:05] Debugging started...
GDB error
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /tmp/SASM/SASMprog.exe...
(gdb) Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401150 <+0>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000401153 <+3>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401154 <+4>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000401157 <+7>: mov    0x404040,%rax
   0x000000000040115f <+15>:    mov    0x404048,%rbx
   0x0000000000401167 <+23>:    cmp    %rbx,%rax
   0x000000000040116a <+26>:    jge    0x401182 <greater>
   0x000000000040116c <+28>:    movabs $0x404064,%rdi
   0x0000000000401176 <+38>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040117b <+43>:    call   0x401040 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000401180 <+48>:    jmp    0x401196 <exit>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) Breakpoint 1 at 0x401150: file /tmp/SASM/program.asm, line 12.
(gdb) Working directory /home/snorlax212/asm.
(gdb) Starting program: /tmp/SASM/SASMprog.exe 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at /tmp/SASM/program.asm:12
12      mov rbp,rsp
(gdb) $1 = 0
(gdb) [01:29:15] Debugging finished.
```

GDB debugging in terminal (gdb jump/break main/step) works fine though. Anybody have idea what to do?

SASM build options:
[This!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PccD.png)
Versions:

```
snorlax212@snorlax212-pc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
snorlax212@snorlax212-pc:~$ nasm --version
NASM version 2.16.01
snorlax212@snorlax212-pc:~$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
snorlax212@snorlax212-pc:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Tried to add -F dwarf option, -m64 -fno-pie options - no help.

Comment: I would try `gdb program` `break main` `run`.

Comment: _"some kind of error"_ is not a helpful problem description.

Comment: @vitsoft gdb terminal debugging works, but I follow learning book and all examples use sasm, wanna resolve this issue if possible.

Comment: @Jester yea, sorry forgot about this when asked, edited.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error because the book says to change the build config. When I removed the "-g" in assembly options, the debugging works.
See screenshot....

[image]

Comment: Yes, this worked for me too, thanks for sharing this!